# Unreported exception IOException

Tags: java, android

I have error:

```
error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Code:

```
ToRestApi rest = new ToRestApi();
HttpResponse response = rest.postToRestApiToken(objEnrolment,"enrolment");

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
final String finalStats = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

I tried to use it in `Try Catch` but it also doesn't work

The error concern: `EntityUtils.toString(entity);`

Comment: *"I tried to use it in Try Catch but it also doesn't work"* then please post that as well

Comment: where and how did you use the try catch? You have to surround all relative code in the try-catch tags

Answer (score 0):

you have a compilation error
you must eigher throw the exception at the end of yout method signature or wrap your code in try catch block